# Protocol Buffers - how is the extensibility and backward compatibility achieved?

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

Please help me understand the backward compatibility and extensibility properties of the protocol buffers' internal implementation.

1. How is backwards compatibility achieved in the face of deleting data fields? I imagine that the generated data access code returns empty values for properties that are not present in the data stream, and the consumer code has to always specifically check for those empty values and act accordingly. How would the empty values be standardized?

   Also in this case, how does the old code "know" that the property is not present in the data stream anymore?

   I imagine that one solution would be that old data is never deleted from the internal stream specification and only replaced with empty values but the same could be probably achieved with internal versioning on the fields.
2. Perhaps a more clear question: how does the old code know to ignore new data added by new versions of the .proto spec? This is probably somewhat more straightforward than 1) by having a size field in the internal serialized structure, and only reading that many bytes at a time, while also only appending new fields at the end of the struct.

Trying to understand all this in order to extend an old data format to provide backward/forward compatibility between code and data as a side project.

Edit: formatting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some background information,
In protocol buffers you define a field like

```
 optional string msg = 1;
```

The number (**1** in this **example**) is used to identify the field in the Data-Message (or Data-Record) and for matching to proto-message used by your program.

Protocol buffers store data Messages like

```
    FieldId1 Data1
    FieldId2 Data2
        .....
    FieldIdn Datan
```

Where fieldId consists of the Field-Number and Field type. If a field **does not** have any data, it is **not stored** in the **output message** (record). So you may have

```
   FieldId3 Data3
   FieldId7 Data7
   FieldId11 Data11
```

---

Answers to your questions:

1. In protocol-buffers every field has one attribute of these attributes: **Required**, **Optional** and **Repeated**. So to *delete* a field you can make it optional and not store any value in it. Some people routinely make most fields optional
2. Protocol Matches the **field-numbers** in the Data-Message with **field-numbers** in the Proto definition. In java at-least, there is are **unknown fields** Map where any extra fields are stored.

---

It is essential you **document** fields (both the **Field-Name** and **Field-Number**) you remove to make sure you **Never reuse a field name/number**.

If you reuse a field, you could break existing code

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

So if a field is declared optional, then that means that the code needs to handle cases where a data field is missing - that makes it at least a little bit forward compatible with the future data definitions from the start. And it looks like the indexing is what gives the data format the flexibility. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Yes to both. I suspect if a field is no longer needed, you would make it optional but keep filling it in. That way sending and receiving systems can be updated independently. The field could be removed totally when all receiving system have been updated.

Comment: There is a caveat if you happen to need a PROXY that must `deserialize` and re-`serialize` the messages. (e.g., an aggregator, or fan-out or ....) In protobuf `syntax 2`, any new unknown fields are preserved across the `deserialize`/`serialize`.  But in protobuf `syntax 3`, the `deserialize` will *drop* any unknown fields.  They will not be passed on to the re-`serialize` phase.  Therefore, update your proxy first, then update your servers and clients -- or leave your proxy using code built from syntax 2.

Comment: @BruceMartin - Do document somewhere which fields you are `removing totally` because accidentally reusing those field names or field ID numbers is likely a breaking change that _may_ cause data loss issues later.  `syntax 3` lets you flag them as reserved, but `syntax 2` doesn't have a built in way to document those changes.